# xterm-256 support for git bash

Tags: windows, git-bash, conemu, mintty, 256color

I am trying to enable xterm 256 color via git bash. It turns out there are 2 ways to start a git bash in Windows.

- windows cmd, run this `git-cmd.exe --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i`
- mintty, run `git-bash.exe`

However seems only the second one support 256 color. The following screenshot is executing result of `cat AnsiColors256.ans` [AnsiColors256.ans](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/blob/master/Release/ConEmu/Addons/AnsiColors256.ans).
[image]

But the downside of `git-bash.exe` is that it can't be integrated into integraded command line tool like `ConEmu`, as indicated on [ConEMU Doc](https://conemu.github.io/en/GitForWindows.html)

> Also, you may run in ConEmu tab git-bash.exe, but this is not recommended, because it runs mintty.exe, which is another terminal.

It actually start an new window instance.

My question is, is there any tweak to config `cmd.exe` to support 256 color like `mintty.exe`? I still want to use a single `ConEMU` instance for all my command line interfaces.

I am using windows git version `git version 2.24.0.windows.2`

Answer (score 0):

> It actually start an new window instance.

a simple "bash" would not start a new windows.

As for the CMD.exe, you might consider using instead the new [Microsoft Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/), as [`Microsoft/Terminal`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal), which is more likely to support 24-bit colors.

Comment: thank you for the info. `git-bash.exe` start a new `mintty` GUI instance, which is outside of `ConEMU` main window. For Microsoft Terminal, the installer prompt me to upgrade to WIN10 1809 version, I am afraid that I can't do this because the work machine is maintained by my company.